# Make chart count strings separately when there is a certain character in between

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

In Google sheets, it is possible to count the number of occurrences of a certain string in each cell of a column, but is it possible to count strings in the same cell separately if there is a certain character in between, such as space?

Example:

```
       Col A

Row 1  A
Row 2  B
Row 3  A
Row 4  B
Row 5  B
Row 6  A B
```

By default, a chart will count `A` 2 times, `B` 3 times and `A B` 1 time. How do I make such a chart count `A` 3 times and `B` 4 times?

Comment: You could use Split(range, delimiter). But this will fragment the text into new cells.

Comment: You can try `=REGEXMATCH(A1,"A")` in Column B (`B1` cell, to be exact) and `=REGEXMATCH(A1,"B")` in Column C (`C1` cell) and use the same formulae all the way through Row 6 - from here, you're free to modulate the formula as required but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: I'm trying to get the chart function to count differently without having to modify the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A, " "))<>"", "♦"&SPLIT(A1:A, " ")&"♠", )), "♦♠")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I'm trying to get the chart function to count differently without having to modify my spreadsheet.

Comment: well thats not possible. this is the only way